# Paradimatic signal for when a user selects a row

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a QTableView that represents a model made of rows and few columns, for example coordinates such as x,y,z. The rows are whole elements and I want to trigger a signal every time a user has chosen a selection. I envision some graphics object changing depending on the selected row.

My current attempt is to do something like

```
ui.tlbView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SelectionMode::SingleSelection);
ui.tlbView->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectionBehavior::SelectRows);
connect(ui.tlbView,&QTableView::clicked ,this,&FancyWidget::rowSelected);
```

This works sometimes, but fails other times. For example clicking on the vertical header does not register while the selection changes. This is bad because I want a signal that triggers every time the selection changes.

This makes me feel like catching the clicked signal is a hack and given that the widget correctly identifies that it is selected, even when my clicked signal is not called. I'm trying to figure out how to match 1:1 the selection state of the widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get notified of selection changes, have a look at [QItemSelectionModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html).
The table view's selection model you can access via [selectionModel()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel). In your case, [QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectionChanged) should be what you need.

```
connect(ui.tlbView->selectionModel(), &QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged, 
        this, &FancyWidget::selectionChanged);
```